# Library for generating HMAC-SHA1 OAuth signature on Android?

Tags: java, android, oauth, sha1, hmac

Using the [specifications](http://code.google.com/apis/accounts/docs/OAuth_ref.html#SigningOAuth) below I need to create an oauth_signature on Android.  I'm looking for a library that handles the boiler plate code in creating a signature for accessing resources via OAuth.

> 1. Construct a signature "base string", which consists of a concatenation of three request elements:
>
>    - The HTTP request method.
>    - The base URL the request is being sent to. This URL should not include any query parameters. When signing calls to Google services, refer to the OAuth specification, Section 9.1.2, for relevant instructions.
>    - A normalized string of the parameters in the request (excluding the oauth_signature parameter). This includes parameters sent in the request header or body, as well as query parameters added to the request URL. To normalize the string, sort the parameters using lexicographical byte value ordering. For more details on normalizing this string, see Section 9.1.1 of the OAuth specification.
> 2. Generate an oauth_signature using one of the following sequences:
>
>    - If your application is registered and you're using HMAC-SHA1, use the OAuth "consumer secret" value generated during registration; this value is displayed on your domain's registration page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used this library for an Android OAuth Client: http://code.google.com/p/oauth-signpost/

Comment: Just did some testing and while not ideal for accessing GAE endpoints, it works!  Thanks.

Comment: @WillMerydith But this can't be used for .net or LinkedIn api

Answer (score 11):

In answer to Will's question on Chris's answer, you could use the built in android javax.crypto.mac to generate the hmacsha1 signature using following code (standard Java JCE provider apis):

```
Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), mac.getAlgorithm());
mac.init(secret);
byte[] digest = mac.doFinal(baseString.getBytes());
byte[] result=Base64.encode(digest, DEFAULT);
```

Where 'secret' would be you text you wanted to encode and 'result' above would be your hash encoded signature.

Comment: `Base64.encodeBase64()` is from Apache's package which doesn't exist in android. Instead, `Base64.encode(string,flag)` should be used.

Comment: thanx @Mahm00d, i have updated my answer. I have also set the flag param to DEFAULT to get the default encode settings (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know anything about OAuth, but you can use [`javax.crypto.Mac`](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/Mac.html) to generate HMAC-SHA1 value (use `HmacSHA1` as the algorithm name):

```
Mac hmac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA1");
```

Comment: And how is that Object used to create a signature?  It doesn't seem clear in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code i used,
just pass the value and key to the hmacSha1().. it returns hmacsha1 string;

```
private static String hmacSha1(String value, String key)
            throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
            InvalidKeyException {
        String type = "HmacSHA1";
        SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), type);
        Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(type);
        mac.init(secret);
        byte[] bytes = mac.doFinal(value.getBytes());
        return bytesToHex(bytes);
    }

    private final static char[] hexArray = "0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();

    private static String bytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        char[] hexChars = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        int v;
        for (int j = 0; j < bytes.length; j++) {
            v = bytes[j] & 0xFF;
            hexChars[j * 2] = hexArray[v >>> 4];
            hexChars[j * 2 + 1] = hexArray[v & 0x0F];
        }
        return new String(hexChars);
    }
```

Comment: what are the parameters? value and key?

Comment: @SubinBabu . inorder to create a hmacsha1  you need to provide two params a key and a message,   the value of these two will depend on your use case.

Comment: For Magento API what we pass in server side it is Consumer Secret
  and Token Secret

Comment: For Oauth i dont think you should be passing CS and TS .  You need to concatenate a set of URL-encoded attributes and parameters to construct the signature base string.  please refer - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/get-started/authentication/gs-authentication-oauth.html#oauth-signature